# react js react-router-dom stores not pass by providers

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using react js with mobx and I'm trying to pass stores in providers and use it but,it seems It's not pass by the providers and I don't have access to it.
in addition when I'm trying to inject the UserStore, the web app is failed and throw an error that UserStore is not available

```
    import { Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {Provider} from 'mobx-react'
import { TodoStore,UserStore, ModalsStore} from '../stores'
import App from './App';
import {Login} from '../screens'

const stores = { UserStore}

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();





export default class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <Provider stores={stores}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>            
                    <Route  component={App}/>            
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

piece of my App component

```
    @observer
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('appProps',props)
    }
    render() {
            ........... 
     }
```

UserStore

```
   import {observable,action} from 'mobx'

class UserStore {
    @observable token = false
    @observable first_name = '';
    @observable last_name = '' 



    @action setUser(data) {
        this.token = data.token;
        this.first_name = data.first_name;
        this.last_name = data.last_name;
    }

    @action updateUser(data) {
        this.first_name = data.first_name;
        this.last_name = data.last_name;
    }

    @action setToken(token){
        this.token = token;
    }

}

const singelton = new UserStore()

export default singelton
```

I'm trying to use the userStore and have access but in console i get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to `@inject('stores')` in your `App` class.
Like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('stores') 
@observer
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.stores);
    
    return (
      <div>{ /* your components */}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically for every class, if you want the store in the props, you have to use `inject`.

Personally, I prefer `import stores from './UserStore'` without `Provider` and `inject`.
In this way, you can access the store directly, and set any observable inside store the same way as `setState`.

The code below is the **MobX** way to use **singleton store** with `observer` and `observable` without using `setState()`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import stores from './userStore';

@observer
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={stores.first_name} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChangeHandler = e => {
    // MobX will setState and trigger the React re-render for you
    stores.first_name  = e.target.value; 
  }
}
```